# Unterschied zwischen "denken an jdm" und "denken an jdn"

Tags: difference

Wir benutzen: *denken an jemandem* (dativ) oder *denken an jemanden* (akkusativ).
Und was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: No, we do not use dative here.

Comment: Trotzdem wird den Ausdruck "denken an" häufig mit dem Dativ verwendet, wie viele Beispiele im Internet davon zeugen. 
+1 für die Frage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Unterschied ist, dass die Variante mit dem Akkusativ korrekt ist und die andere nicht. Du kannst nicht *denken an jemandem*.

Es gibt noch *gedenken* als Äquivalent für *sich erinnern*, was in dieser Form aber mit Genitiv steht, also *jemandes gedenken*, beispielsweise *Wir gedenken heute des 500. Todestages von ...* (nein, *wir gedenken heute dem...* ist nicht korrekt!).

Dann gibt es noch *Im Gedenken an*, aber auch das steht mit Akkusativ. Beispielsweise *Im Gedenken an den 500. Todestag von...*.

Comment: Der Duden definiert *jemandem gedenken* als "besonders schweizerisch". Obwohl ich nicht mal annährend aus der Schweiz kommt, empfinde ich "Ich gedenke ihm" und "Wem gedenkst du" als sehr harmonisch klingend. Der Grund dafür liegt wahrscheinlich darin, dass der Dativ wiefolgt richtig verwendet wird: "Wem gedenkst du deine Stimme zu geben". Natürlich steht hier der Dativ wegen *geben*. Ich wollts nur mal angemerkt haben.

Comment: Aber auch nur, weil hier *gedenken* in der Form für "vorhaben, etwas zu tun" verwendet wird. Siehe dwds.de: *heute bes. **einer** Sache, **eines** Menschen gedenken sowie gedenken, **etw.** zu tun.*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check which one to use, you can refer to the "Questions" that correspond to every case.

Nominativ – (Question: Wer oder was?) „Hans ist Bäcker“

Genitiv – (Question: Wessen?) „Claudias Tasche“; „Wir gedenken der Toten.“; „kraft seines Scharfsinns“ / „der deutschen Sprache mächtig“

Dativ – (Question: Wem?) „jemandem vertrauen“

Akkusativ – (Question: Wen oder was?) „ein Buch verschenken“, „einen Vertrag abschließen“

More on this here: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammatik#Kasus_.E2.80.93_Fall

In your case for example you would ask in the following ways:

```
WRONG: An WEM denke ich? Ich denke an jemandeM

CORRECT: An WEN denke ich? Ich denke an jemandeN
```

You have to learn and understand when to use jemandem and jemanden but if you consider the different cases it will be easier to you to succeed.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I suspect that it does not help. It only helps if you already know the language well enough (e.g. if you are a native speaker) to know what the right case is, but are only confused by some complicated construction.